# Dart FileUpdater works only on one field

Tags: json, dart, plist

I have this piece of code that should update a .plist file

```
Future<String> getJsonAsString() async{
  var config = File('my_file.json');
  var stringContents = await config.readAsString();
  return stringContents;
}

Future<void> updateFields() async {
  var data = jsonDecode(await getJsonAsString());
  FileUpdater.updateFile(
    File('file.plist'),
    Plist(
      'field1',
      data['field1'],
    ),
  );
  FileUpdater.updateFile(
    File('file.plist'),
    Plist(
      'field2',
      data['field2'],
    ),
  );
}
```

**my_file.json** is a very simple json file with no nested data, like this:

```
{"field1": "value1", "field2": "value2"}
```

and **file.plist** is structured like this:

```
...
        <key>field1</key>
        <string>some_value1</string>
        <key>field2</key>
        <string>some_value2</string>
...
```

When I run my code, what I obtain is that only *some_value2* is changed and becomes *value2*, while *filed1* still have *some_value1*, like this:

```
...
        <key>field1</key>
        <string>some_value1</string>
        <key>field2</key>
        <string>value2</string>
...
```

If I delete the second *FileUpdater*, field1 is correctly updated.
Is there something wrong in my code that I can't see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not working as expected because the updateFile() method is an [async method](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_application_id/latest/file_updater_file_updater/FileUpdater/updateFile.html).

In your code, you're not using the await keyword when calling this method, so basically you're asking it to perform a second update before the first update has even begun, in which case (I don't know their exact implementation), it probably discards the first request.

If you use the await keyword:

```
Future<void> updateFields() async {
  var data = jsonDecode(await getJsonAsString());
  await FileUpdater.updateFile(
    File('file.plist'),
    Plist(
      'field1',
      data['field1'],
    ),
  );
  await FileUpdater.updateFile(
    File('file.plist'),
    Plist(
      'field2',
      data['field2'],
    ),
  );
}
```

Then it should work, because the edits will be done one-at-a-time.

Note: Just because a method is async doesn't mean you have to always use await -- In this case, the await keyword is only absolutely required on the first call (because there will be a subsequent call), so it's not absolutely necessary to use it on the second/last call... but I changed both because it's probably better/safer to just always use it.